# MongoDB Get Total Count of Nested Array within an Array Of A Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use the aggregation framework to sum a nested array with a nested array and return the origin document in a sorted order.

So here is what my doc looks like:

```
myColl: {
 _id: 123,
 fruits: [{
   name: apple,
   buyers: [{buyer1}, {buyer2}]
  },
  {
   name: banana,
   buyers: [{buyer1}, {buyer2}, {buyer3}]
 ]
}
```

As you can fruits is array of sub-documents within a myColl doc, and buyers is a nother array of sub-documents inside fruits.

What I want is to count the array of buyers in a document for all fruits. So the above document should have a total buyers of '5'.

Then I want to sort all documents in myColl by the total buyers. I have tried a few things and I can't seem to get it right:

```
db.myColl.aggregate([
{$unwind: '$fruits'},
{$unwind: '$fruits.buyers'},
        {$group: {
            _id: '$fruits.buyers',
            totalBuyers: {$sum: '1'},
                        docs: {$push: '$$ROOT'}
        }},
        {$sort: {'totalBuyers': 1}}])
```

The does not give me the desired result and totalBuyers is always 0. Plus it returns me more results then the total count of myColl. I am guessing it is something to do with the '_id' field.

I had looked at some other SO questions and couldn't find something that matches or works in my case.

My final resort will be to calculate it myself or create a new field to do it but it will make my life a lot easier if I can just run a query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Right, after a lot of tinkering and messing around I had two issues:

1) I had quotes around my number, silly mistake.
2) I need to explicity group by the $$ROOT._id

So here is the solution that works:

```
db.myColl.aggregrate(
[
        {$unwind: '$fruits'},
        {$unwind: '$fruits.buyers'},
        {$group: {
            _id: '$$ROOT._id',
                        doc: {$first: '$$ROOT'},
            totalBuyers: {$sum: 1}
        }},
        {$sort: {'totalBuyers': -1}},
                {$limit : 10 }
    ]
)
```

Note that I had to use '$first' instead of '$push' so that it only retrieves the first document as the document is repeated otherwise for each buyer.